# Test lazy loaded components in Enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

Given a simple App containing multiple lazy loaded routes,

```
import React, { lazy, Suspense } from "react";
import { Route } from "react-router-dom";
import "./styles.css";

const Component = lazy(() => import("./Component"));
const PageNotFound = lazy(() => import("./PageNotFound"));

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Route
        path="/component"
        exact
        render={() => (
          <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading..</div>}>
            <Component />
          </Suspense>
        )}
      />

      <Route
        path="*"
        render={() => (
          <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading..</div>}>
            <PageNotFound />
          </Suspense>
        )}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

How can tests be made to check if those components are being rendered on that specific route?

Here's the App.test with what I tried:

```
import { configure, shallow, mount } from "enzyme";
import Adapter from "@wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17";
import React from "react";
import { MemoryRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import App from "./App";
import Component from "./Component";
import PageNotFound from "./PageNotFound";

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

describe("App", () => {
  it("renders without crashing", () => {
    shallow(<App />);
  });

  it("renders lazy loaded PageNotFound route", () => {
    // Act
    const wrapper = mount(
      <MemoryRouter initialEntries={["/random"]}>
        <App />
      </MemoryRouter>
    );

    // Assert
    // expect(wrapper.containsMatchingElement(<PageNotFound />)).toEqual(true);
    // expect(wrapper.find(PageNotFound)).toHaveLength(1);
    expect(wrapper.exists(PageNotFound)).toEqual(true);
  });
});
```

All 3 assertions don't seem to be working due to Suspense; A working snippet can be found at codesandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-oskar-hjezp) - Make sure to go on the 'tests' tab in order to see the failing tests.

Any suggestion is highly appreciated, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an interesting question which is hard to have a best way to mock since the `lazy(() => import('path/to/file'))` takes a function as argument so we can't detect the value of anonymous function.

But I think I have a solution for you but it's not best to test all cases but a specific case it would work. You would mock as following:

```js
jest.mock('react', () => {
  const React = jest.requireActual('react');
 
  // Always render children as our lazy mock component
  const Suspense = ({ children }) => {
    return children;
  };

  const lazy = () => {
    // `require` component directly as we want to see
    // Why? Above reason
    return require('./PageNotFound').default;
  }

  return {
    ...React,
    lazy,
    Suspense
  };
});
```

#### Update a new way to mock `lazy` function

I think I have a better idea to invoke the `lazy` argument then return as a component as following:

```js
jest.mock('react', () => {
  const React = jest.requireActual('react');
  const Suspense = ({ children }) => {
    return children;
  };
  
  const lazy = jest.fn().mockImplementation((fn) => {
    const Component = (props) => {
      const [C, setC] = React.useState();

      React.useEffect(() => {
        fn().then(v => {
          setC(v)
        });
      }, []);

      return C ? <C.default {...props} /> : null;
    }

    return Component;
  })

  return {
    ...React,
    lazy,
    Suspense
  };
});
```

Then you have to wait the component updated which is returned in mock `lazy` so we wait component to re-paint as following:

```js
// keep warning `act` removed
import { act } from 'react-dom/test-utils';

// A helper to update wrapper
const waitForComponentToPaint = async (wrapper) => {
  await act(async () => {
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve));
    wrapper.update();
  });
};

it("renders PageNotFound", async () => {    
  const wrapper = mount(
    <MemoryRouter initialEntries={["/random"]}>
      <App />
    </MemoryRouter>
  );

  await waitForComponentToPaint(wrapper);

  expect(wrapper.exists(PageNotFound)).toEqual(true);
});

it("renders Component", async () => {    
  const wrapper = mount(
    <MemoryRouter initialEntries={["/component"]}>
      <App />
    </MemoryRouter>
  );

  await waitForComponentToPaint(wrapper);

  expect(wrapper.exists(Component)).toEqual(true);
});
```

#### Another update for link

I've created a `repl.it` link for you to check how it works: https://repl.it/@tmhao2005/js-cra

You can run the test: `yarn test -- lazy`. And browse the code under `src/Lazy`.

Comment: That indeed works well in case we have a single route, but if we have many we'll end up substituting `<lazy />` with `<PageNotFound />` for all of them

Comment: I dropped another suggestion for you

Comment: It now updates all `<lazy />` into `<Component />`, so it still fails upon those checks.. Really appreciate your effort though! I made a playground for it if you want to test out new ideas directly: https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-oskar-hjezp

Comment: Not sure what issue you encountered but I created a `repl.it` for you then you can follow up what you have missed.

Comment: Sorry you were right, that works! I missed the bit of invoking the `waitForComponentToPaint` asynchronously - Everything now works, except for the PageNotFound component, as it seems to exist on any route? If you try adding this assertion `expect(wrapper.exists(PageNotFound)).toEqual(true);`  under "it renders Component", it will still pass successfully, but this is kind of a different type of issue - Do you recall any assertion which checks if a component should show instead?

Comment: Ah. Looks like you forgot to add `<Switch>` component to wrap the routes since it manages the logic to display. I edited here https://repl.it/@tmhao2005/js-cra here for you

Answer (score 0):

**Below is my working version :**

```
import { act, } from 'react-dom/test-utils';

const waitForComponentToPaint = async (wrapper) => {
  await act(async () => {
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve));
    wrapper.update();
  });
};

jest.mock('react', () => {
  const ReactActual = jest.requireActual('react');

  // Always render children as our lazy mock component
  const Suspense = ({
    children,
  }) => children;

  const lazyImport = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
    class SpyComponent extends ReactActual.Component {
      componentDidMount() {}

      render() {
        const {
          path,
        } = this.props;
        const LazyComponent = require(path).default;
        return (
          <>
            {LazyComponent ? <LazyComponent {...this.props} /> : null}
          </>
        );
      }
    }

    return SpyComponent;
  });

  return {
    ...ReactActual,
    lazy: lazyImport,
    Suspense,
  };
});

describe('Render <Header />', () => {
    it('should render a Header', async () => {
      const wrapper = mount(
          <Header />
      );
      await waitForComponentToPaint(wrapper);
      expect(wrapper.find('XXXXXX')).to.have.length(1);
    });          
 });
```

And I added a `path` props when calling the lazy component :

```
   <CustomLazyComponent
      path="./CustomLazyComponent"
    />
```